# Get rid of duplicates in one line instead of two with java 8 stream

Tags: java, list, duplicates, java-stream

Could it be written in one line of code instead of two separate? Because I tried adding `.distinct()` in the first line and somehow it didn't work. I'm not getting the difference here.

```
List<BgwContract> contractListWithDuplicates = monthlyFeePaymentList
           .stream()
           .map(MonthlyFeePayment::getBgwContract)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<BgwContract> contractListWithoutDuplicates = contractListWithDuplicates
           .stream()
           .distinct()
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Oh ok, I put it before `.map()`. Could you explain why it didn't work? Because as I understand I wanted to distinct the stream and which was a list and not the map.

Comment: I added an explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `distinct` with your existing `Stream` itself :

```
List<BgwContract> contractListWithDuplicates = monthlyFeePaymentList
       .stream()
       .map(MonthlyFeePayment::getBgwContract) // Stream<BgwContract>
       .distinct() // here
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you wanted an explanation regarding the correct place of `distinct`:

When you write:

```
List<BgwContract> contractListWithDuplicates = monthlyFeePaymentList
           .stream()
           .distinct()
           .map(MonthlyFeePayment::getBgwContract)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you get a `Stream` of distinct `MonthlyFeePayment` instances (based on the `equals` implementation of `MonthlyFeePayment` class) and then map them to `BgwContract` instances. Two distinct `MonthlyFeePayment` instance may be mapped to the same `BgwContract` instance, so the output `List` may have duplicates.

When you write:

```
List<BgwContract> contractListWithDuplicates = monthlyFeePaymentList
           .stream()
           .map(MonthlyFeePayment::getBgwContract)
           .distinct()
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you first map the `MonthlyFeePayment` instances to `BgwContract` instances, and only then remove the duplicates with `distinct()`, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

With dintinct() the elements are compared using the equals() method. 
You have to override equals() for your BgwContract object.